# Check for valid file name with regex

Tags: regex

I'm try to verify filenames with this schema: `<letter>-<digits>.html`. For example, `t-32782.html` or `f-484774.html`. One letter then many digits then ".html".

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what flavor of regex you're using, but this should work for a number of them.

```
/^\w-\d+\.html$/
```

Comment: This will match: `hello-1.html`, you must include anchors.

Comment: If the filename is `hello-1.html` it will match `o-1.html`.

Answer (score 1):

If the first letter is always lowercase:

```
/^[a-z]-[0-9]+\.html$/
```

If it can be lowercase or uppercase:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]-[0-9]+\.html$/
```

Answer (score 0):

`/[a-z]\-[0-9]+\.html/`

Comment: Hopefully letters are always lowercase. Replace [a-z] with [a-zA-Z].

Comment: the dash doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @theazureshadow or use the 'i' directive
@Ruel the dash may need to be escaped depending upon the regex engine

Comment: Yeah, it would have been nice to know what flavor :) Our code could have been much more precise. Do you know if there's a performance difference between `/[a-zA-Z]/` and `/[a-z]/i`?

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-zA-Z]-[0-9]+\.html$/
```